# Creating a stack with an array, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, class, stack

Pretty simple idea, I am just not sure why it won't work. I am getting an error when I call Stack b = new Stack(5); in main.

Here is main

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
 Stack b = new Stack(5);
  b.push('a');
  b.push('b');
  b.push('c');
  b.printStack();

 }
 }
```

Here is my stack class

```
public class Stack {
 char[] stack;
 int items;

 public Stack(int size) {
 stack = char[size];
 items = 0;

 }

 public void push (char add){
   if (items == stack.length) {
   System.out.println("Stack is full");
  }
   else {
  stack[items] = add;
  }
 }


   public void printStack() {
  if (items == 0)
   return;
   else {
   for (int i = 0; i < items; i++)
  System.out.println(i);
  }
  }
   }
```

Comment: Just to be sure you are practicing, are your aware that Java already has a [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) implementation?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing is:

```
   public Stack(int size) {
     stack = new char[size];
        //^^^you missed new
     items = 0;
   }
```

Meanwhile

```
 stack[items] = add; //should also increment items
```

Comment: I don't care about incrementing items yet, I just want to get this to run. It still doesn't work with new for some reason.

Comment: @Jordan since you never increment items, it is always 0, so your print function does nothing but return.

Comment: I don't care about printing though, I just wanted to resolve the class issue. List of other problems: I can't delete items, I can't remove items, I can't search for items, I can't find the length of the stack, I can't reverse the stack, I can't search the stack, it has a lot of problems.

Comment: I fixed it, I had the file named stack.java and I attempted to rename it Stack.java but it automatically erased the case and made it all lower case. To fix the problem I had to delete the file and then save it again as Stack.java and now it works.

Comment: @Jordan Great! Be sure to name the filename the same as class name in Java,

Answer (score 1):

You need to new up your array.

I can see that your push doesn't increment the items count.  When you push onto your stack, you should also increment the count.

Comment: I don't care about that yet, just trying to get it to run.

Answer (score 0):

in your constructor use

```
 stack = new char[size];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `new` keyword when creating your `stack` array in the constructor.

Furthermore, your `push()` method does not increment `items`, and thus will simply constantly overwrite the first element of the `stack` array.

Finally, your `printStack()` method will not function as you expect it to.  Rather, it will print incremental digits up to the number `5`.  You will need to change the print statement for it to work.

```
System.out.println(stack[i]);
```